# How pass class reference by using deluxe signals in AS3Signals?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I wanna pass class reference when dispatching the deluxe signals in AS3Signals ?

My code here for dispatch,

```
public var signal:DeluxeSignal = new DeluxeSignal(this);
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    signal.dispatch(new GenericEvent());        
}
```

and here i listen,

```
protected function creComp(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    viewB.signal.add(onDeluxDispatched);
}
private function onDeluxDispatched(e:GenericEvent):void
{
    trace(e.target, e.signal);
    trace(e.currentTarget);
    trace("SignalTest.onDeluxDispatched(e)");
}
```

But i received null in trace.

where i am wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

from the documentation of DeluxeSignal class ( https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals/blob/master/src/org/osflash/signals/DeluxeSignal.as )

```
/**
 * Creates a DeluxeSignal instance to dispatch events on behalf of a target object.
 * @param   target The object the signal is dispatching events on behalf of.
 * @param   valueClasses Any number of class references that enable type checks in dispatch().
 * For example, new DeluxeSignal(this, String, uint)
 * would allow: signal.dispatch("the Answer", 42)
 * but not: signal.dispatch(true, 42.5)
 * nor: signal.dispatch()
 *
 * NOTE: Subclasses cannot call super.apply(null, valueClasses),
 * but this constructor has logic to support super(valueClasses).
 */
public function DeluxeSignal(target:Object = null, ...valueClasses)
```

it has to be declared and dispatched that way :

```
public class ClassName {
    public var signal:DeluxeSignal = new DeluxeSignal(this, ClassName);

    private function dispatch():void {
        signal.dispatch(this);
    }
}
```

then retrieved that way in the referenced class :

```
public class Parent {
    private var childClass:ClassName;

    private function bindSignal() {
        childClass.signal.add(signalListener);
    }

    private function signalListener(classReference:ClassName) {
        /* do your stuff with classReference */
    }
}
```

i ran into same issue and that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements you may not need to use DeluxeSignal. I'll use Willo's example to illustrate.

```
public class Parent {
    private var childClass:ClassName;

    private function bindSignal() {
        childClass.signal.add(signalListener);
    }

    private function signalListener(classReference:ClassName) {
        /* do your stuff with classReference */
    }
}
```

Yes, we get a class reference. But this class reference is not the one that was passed to DeluxeSignal when it was instantiated, but instead it is the one that was passed to dispatch.

```
public class ClassName {
    /* this is not the reference to 'this' that the listener gets. in fact,
    all this one does is sit inside the signal as a property */
    public var signal:DeluxeSignal = new DeluxeSignal(this, ClassName);

    private function dispatch():void {
        signal.dispatch(this); // this is the reference that the listener gets
    }
}
```

The reference we passed into the constructor just sits inside a public property called target.

```
public function DeluxeSignal(target:Object = null, ... valueClasses) {
    /* the reference is set as _target and is not used anywhere else in the 
    class other than in the setter/getter */
    _target = target;
    valueClasses = (valueClasses.length == 1 && valueClasses[0] is Array) ? valueClasses[0] : valueClasses;

    super(valueClasses);
}

public function get target():Object { return _target; }

public function set target(value:Object):void {
    if (value == _target) return;
    removeAll();
    _target = value;
}
```

So it seems the idea is to access this property when the listener is called, using a reference to the signal:

```
public class Parent {
    private var childClass:ClassName;

    private function bindSignal() {
        childClass.signal.add(signalListener);
    }

    private function signalListener() {
        /* not passing the reference in the dispatch() call means we can
        still access the target at this point by using... */
        childClass.signal.target;
        /* but it just feels nicer to have the reference provided as an
        argument rather than as a mutable property, right? */
    }
}
```

Technically that works but it doesn't feel great to be getting a reference from what is a mutable property.

Where it might come in handy though is when using a dependency injection framework like Robotlegs, where the signal is injected into a command. Your command wouldn't have a listener with which to be provided a reference in an argument, but it would be able to access the reference from the signal via its target property.

The way Willo used DeluxeSignal here though, you can actually use the plain old Signal class to do exactly the same thing with less overhead.

```
public class ClassName {
    /* note: no pointless use of 'this' in the constructor. instead,
    just the types we will actually be providing to the listener */
    public var signal:Signal = new Signal(ClassName, String);

    private function dispatch():void {
        signal.dispatch(this, "Whatever else you want");
    }
}
```

And on the other end you get this.

```
public class Parent {
    private var childClass:ClassName;

    private function bindSignal() {
        childClass.signal.add(signalListener);
    }

    private function signalListener(classReference:ClassName, foo:String) {
        /* do your stuff with classReference */
    }
}
```

So you get the same result for typing less code and for less inheritance overhead.

Where you might want to use DeluxeSignal though, other than when needing to keep a reference to the target in your DI frameworks, is when you're using native events. DeluxeSignal overrides the dispatch method to do some extra work with those.